# for loop: applying a, b in two lists

Tags: python

I am trying to modify the following script so that my legends are changed to that list in `speeds`. How can I do this without changing the `iterator` list?

```
x = np.arange(10)
iterator = [1, 2, 3]
speeds =[*range(100,300,500)]
for a in iterator:
    plt.plot(x, a*x, label=f'{a}rpm')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

**Modified script**:

```
x = np.arange(10)
iterator = [1, 2, 3]
speeds =[*range(100,300,500)]
for a in iterator and b in speeds:
    plt.plot(x, a*x, label=f'{b}rpm')
plt.legend(loc='best')    
plt.show()
```

**Desired Outcome**: legends are changed to that in `speeds` list
ie,

```
1rpm -> 100rpm
2rpm -> 300rpm
3prm -> 500rpm
```

Comment: Do you want `speeds = [100, 300, 500]` and `for a, b in zip(iterator, speeds)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so sure, what's the usage of

```
[*range(100, 300, 500)]
>>> [100]
```

From your question if I understand correctly what you want is:

```
speeds = [*range(100, 700, 200)]
>>> [100, 300, 500]
```

Now both iterator and speed have a length of 3, so you can rewrite your plotting routine using `zip`

```
for a, b in zip(iterator, speeds):
   plt.plot(x, a*x, label=f'{b}rpm')
plt.legend(loc='best')    
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted but 'ILS' got there first. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`and` is a logical operator, not a general connective as in English.

Combine the lists first with `zip` and then iterate:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = [4,5,6]
>>> for a, b in zip(x, y): print(a, b)
...
1 4
2 5
3 6
```